# Build script with Browserify creates an empty file

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have a simple build script that supposedly should pack all my js modules into a single file using browserify. I have the following code ( inspired from http://www.forbeslindesay.co.uk/post/46324645400/standalone-browserify-builds)

```
function _browserify(srcPath, distPath) {
  var browserify = require('browserify');
  var b = new browserify();
  b.add(srcPath);
  b.bundle().pipe(_fs.createWriteStream(distPath));
  console.log(' '+ distPath +' built.');
}
```

But when I run it, I get a completely empty file. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you try `var b = browserify()`, without `new` operator?

Comment: Tried, nothing changes.

Comment: Then you probably get an error somewhere, add error listener via `b.bundle().on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)}).pipe(...)`

Comment: Like this? 
 `b.bundle().on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)}).pipe(b.bundle().pipe(_fs.createWriteStream(distPath)));`

I get no errors

Comment: No, second `b.bundle()` is unnecessary. `bundle()` returns stream object you should first start listening for its error events and then pipe into `fs.createWriteStream`.

Comment: `b.bundle().on('error', function(err){console.log(err)}).pipe(_fs.createWriteStream(distPath));`

Comment: FIxed, but I still get no error.

Comment: I'm getting empty file too, did you fix this?

Answer (score 2):

okay, definitely spent waaaay too much of my evening on this, but this turns out to be an async issue. you're most likely getting an error in there somewhere, but grunt is killing off the process before the error callback has a chance to be called. grunt provides a nifty async method on each task's context that you have to use to let grunt know that this is an async task (and therefore needs to wait for everything to be finito). something like...

```
grunt.registerTask('build', function () {
    var done = this.async();

    browserify({ debug: true })
        .add('./src/main.js')
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./target/bundle.js')
        .on('end', done);
});
```